# substring search in Conditional response

Tags: google-cloud-platform, substring, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx

I have created a simple Agent in Dialogflow CX. Before performing the next webhook call I want to check user-entered city is present in the `$session.params.cities`.

By referring to [conditional response doc](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/condition#comp), I have used **HAS (:**) operator like below

```
if $session.params.cities : $session.params.city
 Validating the city name
else
 Invalid city
endif
```

Example values:

```
$session.params.cities = "A, B, C, D"

$session.params.city = "B"
```

But this is not working, it is entering to else case. According to the doc, it says `The RHS is type casted to the same type as the LHS before comparing.` How can I perform a substring search?

Comment: Was it resulting to else case with hard coded value: `if $session.params.cities : "B"`?

Comment: For hardcoded value(`if $session.params.cities : "B"`), it will not enters to `else` case. But If I use `$session.params.city` then it enters to `else` case.

Comment: Have you considered to adjust `if..elif` [construction](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/fulfillment#cond) in conditional response? I guess the RHS holder doesn't support the [parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter) but only values.